# I am making a java program and wanted to add a scrollpain in the main framework

Tags: java

I am making a java program and wanted to add a scrollpain in the main framework.
But I have no idea how to do it. If someone could pass me the code of how I would do it, I would appreciate it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIAE2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JTextField area;
private JLabel label2;
private JButton 
buton1,buton2,buton3,buton4;buton5,buton6,buton7,buton8;buton9,buton10,buton11;
private JScrollPane sp1;

public GUIAE2(){

setLayout(null);
setTitle("ejercicios java");
getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));



buton1 = new JButton("Ejercicio 1 (Expresiones regulares)");
buton1.setBounds(350,40,700,60);
buton1.setBackground(new Color (0,0,224));
buton1.setFont(new Font("andale mono",1,14));
buton1.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
buton1.addActionListener(this);
add(buton1);



}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
      GUIAE2 ventanabienvenida = new GUIAE2();
      ventanabienvenida.setBounds(0,0,350,450);
      ventanabienvenida.setVisible(true);
      ventanabienvenida.setResizable(true);
      ventanabienvenida.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is:

```
private JScrollPane sp1;

public GUIAE2() {

setLayout(null);
setTitle("ejercicios java");
getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
// first initialize the JScrollPane:
sp1 = new JScrollPane();
// now let's add the JScrollPane to the content pane:
getContentPane().add(sp1);

buton1 = new JButton("Ejercicio 1 (Expresiones regulares)");
...
buton1.addActionListener(this);
// we also add other elements to the scroll pane so it has content that
// can be scrolled:
sp1.add(buton1);

}
```

But instead of handling writing the UI code by yourself, I would highly recommend to use UI tools like the UI Builder that is integrated in NetBeans IDE. There you can build your GUI with drag and drop.

Basically the UI is made up like a tree where your JFrame is the root and you can add branches, i.e. more content to the branches.